# Wrong number of arguments when sending Email with AutoExec

Tags: email, vba, ms-access, arguments

I'm trying to send an email through a function which I downloaded from C.Pearson. When I try to make it work I get the error: "The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments."

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function SendEMail(Subject As String, _
        FromAddress As String, _
        ToAddress As String, _
        MailBody As String, _
        SMTP_Server As String, _
        Optional BodyFileName As String, _
        Optional Attachments As Variant = Empty) As Boolean

Dim MailMessage As CDO.Message
Dim N As Long
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim S As String
Dim Body As String
Dim Recips() As String
Dim Recip As String
Dim NRecip As Long

' ensure required parameters are present and valid.
If Len(Trim(Subject)) = 0 Then
    SendEMail = False
    Exit Function
End If

If Len(Trim(FromAddress)) = 0 Then
    SendEMail = False
    Exit Function
End If

If Len(Trim(SMTP_Server)) = 0 Then
    SendEMail = False
    Exit Function
End If

' Clean up the addresses
Recip = Replace(ToAddress, Space(1), vbNullString)
Recips = Split(Recip, ";")

For NRecip = LBound(Recips) To UBound(Recips)
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Create a CDO Message object.
    Set MailMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        SendEMail = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    With MailMessage
        .Subject = Subject
        .From = FromAddress
        .To = Recips(NRecip)
        If MailBody <> vbNullString Then
            .TextBody = MailBody
        Else
            If BodyFileName <> vbNullString Then
                If Dir(BodyFileName, vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
                    ' import the text of the body from file BodyFileName
                    FNum = FreeFile
                    S = vbNullString
                    Body = vbNullString
                    Open BodyFileName For Input Access Read As #FNum
                    Do Until EOF(FNum)
                        Line Input #FNum, S
                        Body = Body & vbNewLine & S
                    Loop
                    Close #FNum
                    .TextBody = Body
                Else
                    ' BodyFileName not found.
                    SendEMail = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If ' MailBody and BodyFileName are both vbNullString.
        End If

        If IsArray(Attachments) = True Then
            ' attach all the files in the array.
            For N = LBound(Attachments) To UBound(Attachments)
                ' ensure the attachment file exists and attach it.
                If Attachments(N) <> vbNullString Then
                    If Dir(Attachments(N), vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
                        .AddAttachment Attachments(N)
                    End If
                End If
            Next N
        Else
            ' ensure the file exists and if so, attach it to the message.
            If Attachments <> vbNullString Then
                If Dir(CStr(Attachments), vbNormal) <> vbNullString Then
                    .AddAttachment Attachments
                End If
            End If
        End If
        With .Configuration.Fields
            ' set up the SMTP configuration
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTP_Server
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            .Update
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        ' Send the message
        .Send
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            SendEMail = True
        Else
            SendEMail = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
Next NRecip

End Function


Public Sub EmailSendSub()
SendEMail ("My Email", "spetsnaz307@gmail.com", "spetsnaz307@hotmail.co.nz","Hello", SMTP_Server:="smtp.gmail.com", "D:\Other\modemail.bas", Attachments:=Empty)

End Sub
```

I have a macro named 'autoexec', and this code is in a module called 'modEmail'.

My macro's action is RunCode and the Function Name is: 'SendEMail()'

How can I fix this error? I've been playing around with this code for days and I can't seem to come up with a solution.

Note: *My port 25 is blocked by my ISP, will that cause this particular error?*

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: check how you are calling it - just using `sendmail()` will not work, you will have to fill in data for all the parameters not listed as optional e.g. `sendmail("MySubject","from.me@example.com","to.him@example.com","text that makes up the email","mysmtpserveraddress")`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the `Function` declaration in the VBA code, that function expects you to supply the Subject line, the FromAddress, the ToAddress, etc., as arguments. If your macro is simply calling `SendEMail()` (without any arguments) then that is the problem because you're not telling the function what to send, or to whom.

The function call needs to be something more like

```
SendEMail("this is the Subject", "sender@example.com", "recipient@example.com", ...
```

Comment: Ok I edited my question with the code I used, and it gives me the Compile Error: `Expected: Named Parameter` for the BodyFileName part of it?